# sql time calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have create the following sql in Oracle db and it works. Now I need the to add hold and unhold time for every phase in case to change status into hold and some way to calculate every hold-unhold time and remove the time from dead line
example problemid:111  phase:Classification   complexity :minor deadline: 17/1/2016 (2 days) 12:00 let's say that i put status hold today  and unhold it tommorow on 8:00 the result must be problemid:111  phase:Classification   complexity :minor deadline: 18/1/2016 (2 days) 7:00.

So I want to calculate the time that is on hold and change the deadline dynamically,
any idea?

```
select
ProblemID,
CASE --this calculate the next phase
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null THEN 'Acknowledge'
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null THEN 'Classification'
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null THEN 'Feasibility'  
END
PHASES,  
CASE --this add the deadline for every phase
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1 THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1  THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1  THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 2  THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 2 THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
         WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 2  THEN trunc(CreationDate)+2
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+5
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'medium' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+5
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'major' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+10
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN 
          CASE
            WHEN (trunc(InsertionDate)+5-TRUNC(sysdate,'IW')+1) = 7 then trunc(InsertionDate)+6
            WHEN (trunc(InsertionDate)+5-trunc(sysdate,'IW')+1) = 6 then trunc(InsertionDate)+7
            END
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'medium' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+5
         WHEN phases = 'Acknowledgement' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'major' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+10
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+5
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'medium' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+10
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'major' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+20
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+10
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'medium' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+20
         WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'major' THEN trunc(InsertionDate)+30 
END            
DEADLINE, 
CASE   --this calculate state       
        WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN
        CASE
            WHEN (trunc(CreationDate)+3-TRUNC(sysdate,'IW')+1) = 7 THEN 'OK' 
            WHEN (trunc(CreationDate)+3-trunc(sysdate,'IW')+1) = 6 THEN 'OK' 
            ELSE 'DELAYED' 
        END
        WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1  and trunc(CreationDate)+3 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'          
        WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 1  and trunc(CreationDate)+3 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'           
        WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 2  and trunc(CreationDate)+3 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'        
        WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 2  and trunc(CreationDate)+3 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'          
        WHEN phases is null and INSERTIONDATE is null and Priority = 2  and trunc(CreationDate)+3 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Acknowledge' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'minor' and trunc(CreationDate)+6 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Acknowledge' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'medium' and trunc(CreationDate)+6 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Acknowledge' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'major' and trunc(CreationDate)+11 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Acknowledge' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'minor' THEN 
         CASE
            WHEN (trunc(CreationDate)+5-TRUNC(sysdate,'IW')+1) = 7 THEN 'OK' 
            WHEN (trunc(CreationDate)+5-trunc(sysdate,'IW')+1) = 6 THEN 'OK' 
            ELSE 'DELAYED' 
        END
        WHEN phases = 'Acknowledge' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'medium'  and trunc(CreationDate)+6 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Acknowledge' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'major'  and trunc(CreationDate)+11 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'minor' and trunc(CreationDate)+6 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'medium' and trunc(CreationDate)+11 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 1 and Complexity = 'major' and trunc(CreationDate)+21 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'minor' and trunc(CreationDate)+11 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'medium' and trunc(CreationDate)+21 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'
        WHEN phases = 'Classification' and INSERTIONDATE is not null and Priority = 2 and Complexity = 'major' and trunc(CreationDate)+31 <= trunc(SYSDATE) THEN 'DELAYED'         
        ELSE 'OK'       
END
STATE
from problem_PHASES
```

Comment: Please make your question more readable (split it up in multiple parts, throw in some more punctuation marks). Also, I think the if statements for checking priorities and complexities don't belong in your SQL code, but  that's just my opinion.

Comment: hello,why the statements for checking priorities and complexities don't belong in your SQL code? this statement checking something else which works already.I need to add some code just for time calculation!All the project is to show which is the problem id, the current phase, dead line for current phase, the next phase, the dead line for completion and the state if it is delay. But i need to calculate the hold time in order to dynamically change the deadlines!

Comment: How would someone looking at this query know whether something is "on hold" or not? What columns are to be used for your "time calculation"? What is this "time calculation" supposed to be?

Comment: @Ptz because, **in my opinion**, such business logic should be in the application server code, not in the database fetching code. (I think most developers feel this way, for example see [this article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/11/11/is-sql-a-good-place-for-business-logic/))

Comment: i have not create any column for "time calculation" i need help for this!!